# What is wicked taking so long during boot?

Tags: boot, opensuse, systemd

This is wicked 0.6.12 and systemd 210 on openSUSE 13.2. Networkmanager is not installed. The network interface is configured with a static IPv4 address. Plymouth is not installed because I prefer to see what's going on.

The boot time is ridiculously long. The system is just sitting there doing apparently nothing before the graphical target comes up.

[Output of `systemd-analyze plot`](http://imgh.us/bootchart.svgz)

Output of `sudo journalctl -b | ack -C 25 wicked` (time gap occurs before `11:29:01`):

```
Nov 14 11:28:48 ascorbic lvm[458]: /dev/sdb: open failed: No medium found
Nov 14 11:28:48 ascorbic lvm[458]: No volume groups found
Nov 14 11:28:48 ascorbic kernel: EXT4-fs (sda4): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: acl,user_xattr
Nov 14 11:28:48 ascorbic systemd-journal[320]: Runtime journal is using 8.0M (max allowed 396.9M, trying to leave 595.3M free of 3.8G available → current limit 396.9M).
Nov 14 11:28:48 ascorbic avahi-daemon[494]: Found user 'avahi' (UID 491) and group 'avahi' (GID 489).
Nov 14 11:28:48 ascorbic avahi-daemon[494]: Successfully dropped root privileges.
Nov 14 11:28:48 ascorbic avahi-daemon[494]: avahi-daemon 0.6.31 starting up.
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic kernel: vboxdrv: Found 2 processor cores.
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic kernel: vboxdrv: fAsync=0 offMin=0x2a8 offMax=0x17a3
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic kernel: vboxdrv: TSC mode is 'synchronous', kernel timer mode is 'normal'.
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic kernel: vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 4.3.18_OSE (interface 0x001a0008).
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic avahi-daemon[494]: Loading service file /etc/avahi/services/sftp-ssh.service.
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic avahi-daemon[494]: Loading service file /etc/avahi/services/ssh.service.
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic avahi-daemon[494]: Network interface enumeration completed.
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic avahi-daemon[494]: Registering HINFO record with values 'X86_64'/'LINUX'.
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic avahi-daemon[494]: Server startup complete. Host name is ascorbic.local. Local service cookie is 142331764.
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic avahi-daemon[494]: Service "ascorbic" (/etc/avahi/services/ssh.service) successfully established.
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic avahi-daemon[494]: Service "ascorbic" (/etc/avahi/services/sftp-ssh.service) successfully established.
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic kernel: NET: Registered protocol family 17
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic kernel: No iBFT detected.
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic kernel: vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic vboxdrv[493]: Starting VirtualBox kernel modules..done
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic kernel: r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic kernel: r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic wickedd[528]: lo: address 127.0.0.1 covered by a static lease
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic dns-resolver[606]: ATTENTION: You have modified /etc/resolv.conf. Leaving it untouched...
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic dns-resolver[608]: You can find my version in /etc/resolv.conf.netconfig
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic wickedd[528]: dns-resolver: ATTENTION: You have modified /etc/resolv.conf. Leaving it untouched...
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic wickedd[528]: dns-resolver: You can find my version in /etc/resolv.conf.netconfig
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic wickedd[528]: ATTENTION: You have modified /etc/resolv.conf.  Leaving it untouched...
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic wickedd[528]: You can find my version in /etc/resolv.conf.netconfig ...
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic wickedd[528]: subprocesses exited with error
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic wickedd[528]: failed to install generic settings
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic wickedd[528]: lo: address ::1 covered by a static lease
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic dns-resolver[733]: ATTENTION: You have modified /etc/resolv.conf. Leaving it untouched...
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic dns-resolver[735]: You can find my version in /etc/resolv.conf.netconfig
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic wickedd[528]: dns-resolver: ATTENTION: You have modified /etc/resolv.conf. Leaving it untouched...
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic wickedd[528]: dns-resolver: You can find my version in /etc/resolv.conf.netconfig
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic wickedd[528]: ATTENTION: You have modified /etc/resolv.conf.  Leaving it untouched...
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic wickedd[528]: You can find my version in /etc/resolv.conf.netconfig ...
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic wickedd[528]: subprocesses exited with error
Nov 14 11:28:49 ascorbic wickedd[528]: failed to install generic settings
Nov 14 11:28:51 ascorbic kernel: r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link up
Nov 14 11:28:51 ascorbic kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp3s0: link becomes ready
Nov 14 11:28:51 ascorbic avahi-daemon[494]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.222.165.
Nov 14 11:28:51 ascorbic avahi-daemon[494]: New relevant interface enp3s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Nov 14 11:28:51 ascorbic avahi-daemon[494]: Registering new address record for 192.168.222.165 on enp3s0.IPv4.
Nov 14 11:28:51 ascorbic dns-resolver[877]: ATTENTION: You have modified /etc/resolv.conf. Leaving it untouched...
Nov 14 11:28:51 ascorbic dns-resolver[879]: You can find my version in /etc/resolv.conf.netconfig
Nov 14 11:28:51 ascorbic wickedd[528]: dns-resolver: ATTENTION: You have modified /etc/resolv.conf. Leaving it untouched...
Nov 14 11:28:51 ascorbic wickedd[528]: dns-resolver: You can find my version in /etc/resolv.conf.netconfig
Nov 14 11:28:51 ascorbic wickedd[528]: ATTENTION: You have modified /etc/resolv.conf.  Leaving it untouched...
Nov 14 11:28:51 ascorbic wickedd[528]: You can find my version in /etc/resolv.conf.netconfig ...
Nov 14 11:28:51 ascorbic wickedd[528]: subprocesses exited with error
Nov 14 11:28:51 ascorbic wickedd[528]: failed to install generic settings
Nov 14 11:28:52 ascorbic avahi-daemon[494]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::5246:5dff:fea0:251e.
Nov 14 11:28:52 ascorbic avahi-daemon[494]: New relevant interface enp3s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Nov 14 11:28:52 ascorbic avahi-daemon[494]: Registering new address record for fe80::5246:5dff:fea0:251e on enp3s0.*.
Nov 14 11:29:01 ascorbic wicked[532]: lo              up
Nov 14 11:29:01 ascorbic wicked[532]: enp3s0          up
Nov 14 11:29:01 ascorbic sshd-gen-keys-start[969]: Checking for missing server keys in /etc/ssh
Nov 14 11:29:01 ascorbic cron[967]: (CRON) INFO (Syslog will be used instead of sendmail.)
Nov 14 11:29:01 ascorbic cron[967]: (CRON) INFO (RANDOM_DELAY will be scaled with factor 95% if used.)
Nov 14 11:29:01 ascorbic cron[967]: (CRON) INFO (running with inotify support)
Nov 14 11:29:01 ascorbic iscsiadm[981]: iscsiadm: No records found
Nov 14 11:29:01 ascorbic sshd[982]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Nov 14 11:29:01 ascorbic sshd[982]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Nov 14 11:29:01 ascorbic chronyd[986]: chronyd version 1.29.1 starting
Nov 14 11:29:01 ascorbic chronyd[986]: Could not open RTC file (null) for reading
Nov 14 11:29:01 ascorbic chronyd[986]: Set system time, error in RTC = 0.000000
Nov 14 10:29:01 ascorbic chronyd[986]: Linux kernel major=3 minor=16 patch=6
Nov 14 10:29:01 ascorbic chronyd[986]: hz=100 shift_hz=7 freq_scale=1.00000000 nominal_tick=10000 slew_delta_tick=833 max_tick_bias=1000 shift_pll=2
Nov 14 10:29:01 ascorbic chronyd[986]: Frequency 10.585 +/- 0.080 ppm read from /var/lib/chrony/drift
Nov 14 10:29:01 ascorbic chronyd[986]: Can't initialise from real time clock, driver not loaded
Nov 14 10:29:01 ascorbic chronyd[974]: Starting chronyd: ..done
Nov 14 10:29:01 ascorbic display-manager[987]: /etc/vconsole.conf available
Nov 14 10:29:01 ascorbic display-manager[987]: KEYMAP: de-latin1-nodeadkeys
Nov 14 10:29:01 ascorbic display-manager[987]: Command: localectl set-keymap de-latin1-nodeadkeys
Nov 14 10:29:01 ascorbic dbus[505]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.locale1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.locale1.service'
Nov 14 10:29:01 ascorbic dbus[505]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.locale1'
Nov 14 10:29:01 ascorbic display-manager[987]: Starting service kdm..done
Nov 14 10:29:01 ascorbic pdns_recursor[973]: PowerDNS Recursor 3.6.2 (jenkins@autotest.powerdns.com) (C) 2001-2014 PowerDNS.COM BV
Nov 14 10:29:01 ascorbic pdns_recursor[973]: Using 64-bits mode. Built on 20141030174804 by abuild@cloud108, gcc 4.8.1 20130909 [gcc-4_8-branch revision 202388].
Nov 14 10:29:01 ascorbic pdns_recursor[973]: PowerDNS comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it according to the terms of the GPL version 2.
Nov 14 10:29:01 ascorbic pdns_recursor[973]: Reading random entropy from '/dev/urandom'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DHCP timeout is taking so long. Edit `/etc/sysconfig/network/dhcp` and change the values for `DHCLIENT_WAIT_AT_BOOT` and `DHCLIENT6_WAIT_AT_BOOT`.

Comment: What is best value? Is it any issue to set 0?

Answer (score 1):

Try to run `systemd-analyze critical-chain`. I think the output is easier to read than the log. Well, it might just confirm that wicked is the culprit. I have no experience with wicked yet, but I would try to start it under strace to see where it hangs/times out or to run tcpdump in parallel to see what it tries to do on the net.

Edit: Oops, I had missed your link to the plot. So I guess critical-chain will indeed just show that wicked is the culprit... So try strace and/or tcpdump.

Edit2: for using strace I would try

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/strace -ff -o /tmp/wicked.str -ttt -T /usr/sbin/wicked --systemd ifup all
```

in the wicked unit file.

Disclaimer: Untested. Sorry, don't have a suitable test system handy.